# Can we get http_code of a server through its IP Address Instead of URL Through Curl

Tags: php, curl

I have searched a lot, but could'nt find a correct solution.

Actually I want to check weather a server is down or up. I already done it through

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

echo $url . 'HTTP code: ' . $httpcode . '<br>';
```

But I have IP of server instead of URL's. so I want to do it through IP and PORT Instead OF URLs

I know the alternatives like `exec() , fsockopen()`, etc.

Comment: I need a fastest solution to check a server is Down or UP by using Server IP and PORT.

Comment: What is the issue, if you run the above code you will get results by using IP address. So what is exactly you want.

Comment: I want to use IP address instead of URL in curl Option.

Comment: Then _do_ that, what is the actual _problem_ …? `$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:1234';`